# Именованные каналы c#

Tags: c#

Метод NamedPipe(Client/Server)Stream.Read разве не синхронный. Вот в сокетах, он синхронен, есть ассинхронные, но это понятно, но вот с именованными непонятно зачем нужен ReadAsync?
Типо read вызвал, если возвратил, то возвратил, нет - нет. Че к чему.

Comment: Я экспериментировал, оказался синхронным, но для уверенности хочу спросить

Comment: [Точно синхронным](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.readasync?view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_Stream_ReadAsync_System_Byte___System_Int32_System_Int32)?

Comment: Не уточнил - про read. Еще немного поэкспериметировал, понял для чего read async, и тут вопрос встал - Я отправил одновременно со стороны сервера и клиента, и тут все зависло, при том исключения не генерировались. Как быть?

Comment: Это уже другой вопрос. Сформулируйте один конкретный вопрос, чтобы на него можно было дать один конкретный ответ, отредактируйте пост. (кнопка "править")

Comment: `Как быть?` - изучать, что такое deadlock. Без показанного кода сказать что-либо сложно.